QGIS: "Export Mesh on Grid" not working with "Export Vector Option" enabled?
I need to sample the vector data from a Mesh to a grid, and was hoping to use the Processing Script Export Mesh on Grid, with the Export Vector Option enabled.
(pic. 1)
Unfortunately the whole attribute table exists only of 0 or nan's. (pic. 2)


Interestingly enough the script Export Mesh Vertices works just fine, although the same settings as in the Grid-function were used (pic. 3/4)
Anyone had the same problems before, or knows a workaround? Not quite sure if it's just me or this may be considered a bug though...


